# Sphinx field-start and field-end extended2 search not working

Tags: php, sphinx

I know 'not working' is never a good start when asking for help but I have been at this on and off for months and I've got virtually nowhere.

So far I have at least determined I CAN get the field-start/end operaters working but ONLY when I stick in a space character like:

`@gametitle "^diablo$ "`

Strangely that returns JUST the game `Diablo`, however:

`@gametitle "^diablo$"`

Returns ALL games with Diablo in the name. Now that's great, I apparently can rely on the fact this extra space character will apply proper matching of the game titles (it seems to work with `"^age of empires$ "` too).

However when it comes to my OTHER field, the one I actually want to do this full field matching on (@console), I get no such luck. I simply get NO results (if I try and do `"^PlayStation$ "`), or else I get all the results with playstation in the console field (i.e. the PS1/2/3 and portable) when I do `"^PlayStation$"`.

Now the only difference between the `@gametitle` and `@console` fields is that the console field contains some NULL entries. I tried to get around this by selecing the string 'NULL' with an IF statement in MySQL (that's my source) but no joy. In addition, both the console and game title fields are VARCHAR(255) in MySQL.

I'm hoping someone will have some a-ha moment with what I've mentioned with regards to the extra space making this thing work, but I'm not holding my breath! Anyway enough of my pessimism, looking forward to your thoughts.

I am using the PHP API provided by sphinx which I'm extending to make minor changes. I am querying a `searchd` instance, which is Sphinx v1.10-beta. Here are the query logs:

```
[...] 0.024 sec [ext2/1/attr- 7 (0,50)] [application] @gametitle "^age of empires$"
[...] 0.024 sec [ext2/1/attr- 1 (0,50)] [application] @gametitle "^age of empires$ "
```

There you can really see how the addition of the space knocks the record count down from 7 to 1, when really you should expect them both to return 1...

Comment: Could you please show the PHP code with search query?

Comment: For such cases it is better to use filters. You could make crc32 filter for titles and use them like that: $cl->SetFilter('title_flt', array(crc32('diablo'));

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I will try that when I'm back at work and post the code if it doesn't work out to be suitable.

Comment: Do beware that PHP CRC32 function returns a signed integer - needs converting to unsigned. See the php documentation. Just useing crc32() function directly will fail sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain this is a bug in Sphinx.

I've added it to the Issue Tracker
http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=909

but so far it hasn't been acknowledged

Comment: In case is not noted. The bug report is now marked as resolved. Can download a fixed version of sphinx from SVN :)

Comment: I'm glad that's been fixed but I think it turns out not to be the actual issue here. I actually finally fixed this by taking Yaroslav's advice and implementing a CRC32 of the title field and doing a filter (thank you for advising regarding the unsigned CRC32, though, as at first it did not work until I read that)! I'm extremely happy right now.